# jQuery / JavaScript How can I find the left inner edge of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now I am toying around with an idea in my head, and have been looking for answers how to tackle a particular question of mine, as I haven't been able to do it in the past either.

What I want to do is take 2+ elements. One main wrapper element and 1 or more elements within that wrapper. What I want to do is when the right outer edge of the elements within the wrapper meets the wrappers left inner edge I want to fire off a function. So I can do a couple things based on the overall idea I have. However finding those edges or really any edges in general have always been a problem for me. I'm sure its possible, but how is the question.

Comment: I read once jQuery UI has intersect API for the drag and drop, worth checking it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answer is to use `position().left` to get the correct position of an element within a parent element.

```
var boxPosX = $('#box').position().left;
```

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ejuxuw/3/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
function custom(){
  $('#wrapper').css({background:'yellow'}).text('TOUCHDOWN!'); 
}

$(window).resize(function(){     
  var wrapperW = $('#wrapper').outerWidth(true);
  var boxW = $('#box').width();

  var boxPosX = $('#box').position().left;

  var touched = wrapperW - (boxW+boxPosX);

  if( touched <= 0 ){
     custom() ;
  }      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's offset method: http://api.jquery.com/offset/ . You'll need to work out the padding and margin to add in to it, but it I believe it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://api.jquery.com/position/ you'll need the .position method.

"The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent. Contrast this with .offset(), which retrieves the current position relative to the document. When positioning a new element near another one and within the same containing DOM element, .position() is the more useful.

Returns an object containing the properties top and left."

Hope this helps.